# Trinomial Theorem for negative exponents

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I just learned of binomial theorem for negative integers (or in that case any real $n$).  Does such a theorem exist for the trinomial theorem
$$(a+b+c)^n$$
and has there been work done?

I would think that it could logically be extended in the same way as the binomial.  You could look at
$$(a+b+c)^{-n}$$
The first step would be defining the trinomial coefficient.  So
$$\binom{-n}{i_1,i_2,i_3}=\frac{(-n)(-n-1)(-n-2)...}{i_1!i_2!i_3!}$$

But this really doesn't make sense to me.  It seems to work in the binomial case since you have $(n-k)!$ in the denominator.  For example, for $n=6, i_1=1, i_2=2, i_3=3$, then
$$\binom{-6}{1,2,3}=\frac{-6(-6-1)(-6-2)(-6-3)}{1!2!3!}=(-1)^4\frac{6\cdot 7\cdot 8\cdot 9}{1!2!3!}=(-1)\frac{9!}{1!2!3!5!}$$

But this would not be the only interpretation, because which $i_j$ would you expand to?  Any insight?

EDIT:
Reconsidering:  If I have

$$\binom{n}{i_1,i_2,i_3}$$
Since it is true that $n=i_1+i_2+i_3$, I can write it as
$$\binom{n}{i_1,i_2,i_3}=\binom{n}{i_1,i_2,n-i_1-i_2}$$

$$\binom{n}{i_1,i_2,n-i_1-i_2}=\frac{n!}{i_1!i_2!(n-i_1-i_2)!}=\frac{n(n-1)n-2)...(n-i_1-i_2+1)}{i_1!i_2!}$$
Now considering $negative$ $n$, 
$$\binom{-n}{i_1,i_2,n-i_1-i_2}=\frac{-n(-n-1)(n-2)...(-n-i_1-i_2+1)}{i_1!i_2!}$$
$$=(-1)^{i_1+i_2}\frac{n(n+1)(n-2)...(n+i_1+i_2-1)}{i_1!i_2!}$$
$$=(-1)^{i_1+i_2}\frac{(n+i_1+i_2-1)!}{i_1!i_2!(n-1)!}$$
$$=(-1)^{i_2+i_3}\binom{n+i_1+i_2-1}{i_1,i_2,n-1}$$

Does this make sense?

Comment: Binomial series :$(1+x)^k=1 + kx + (k(k-1)/2 )x^2 + ...$ for real $k$ and $x <1$.  In your case , suppose $ a+b>c$ . Then $(a+b+c)^n=(a+b)^n(1 + c/(a+b))^k$ . Now you can just use binomial series with $x=c/(a+b)$

Comment: Could I also consider that $\binom{n}{i_1,i_2,i_3}=\binom{n}{i_1,i_2,n-i_1-i_2}$, since $i_1+i_2+i_3=n?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $|b+c| < |a|$,

$$\eqalign{(a+b+c)^{n} &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty {n \choose k} a^{n-k} (b+c)^k\cr
& = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^k {n \choose k} {k \choose j} a^{n-k} b^{k-j} c^j\cr}$$

Comment: That is nice.  Thank you.

Comment: So when considering the negative integers $n$, we can just convert the binomial coefficient using the standard binomial conversion, change $a^{n-k}$ to $a^{-1(n+k)}=\frac1{a^{n+k}}$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, see [multinomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem). It's pretty famous generalization of binomial one.

Comment: Thank you, I know of the multinomial theorem, but from what I read, it is for nonnegative integers $n$.  My question is dealing with $negative$ and $real$ numbers.

Comment: Well, $x^{-n}$ is just $1/x^n$. If you want to compute $(a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_m)^{-m}$, it equals $1/(a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_m)^{m}$. Real numbers follow from this.

Comment: You are right.  Thank you for your help!